# Internal and external AD users can access folder shared via link sharing even without using that specific link?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharing, guest-access

I have couple of folders in a document library.

I have assigned an internal and an external guest AD user with access to such a folder via link sharing with that specific user. I understand that this breaks inheritence on that folder.

Now I was expecting that the user can access the folder only via this specific link.

However they can use the generic document library link (user sees only the folder they have access to) or the generic folder link to access that folder.

But is this expected that the above links should work? And in that case what's the difference between link sharing and direct access in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because the permissions are assigned to the user, not the link.

- Direct Access: You give certain people permission to see a folder. They can see it because you specifically allowed them.
- Sharing Link: You create a special link to a folder. Anyone with this link can see the folder, even if they weren’t specifically allowed.

In your case, you gave people access with a **link**. *But once they have access, they can see the folder directly, not just through the link.* The link is just a way to give them access in the first place.

Comment: As mentioned in my question, `I have assigned an internal and an external guest AD user with access to such a folder via link` - this means I have done link sharing.

Comment: Yes however once these users have access to the folder, they can reach it directly, not just through the shared link. The shared link is just one way they got access initially. After that, they can use any valid path to reach the folder.

Comment: But if I have not explicitly given permission on the folder. I have only given permission via link. So how are those users able to use the generic link as well?

Comment: You’re essentially granting access to the users who receive that link. This means that the users are given permission to access the folder, not just the link. So, even if you haven’t explicitly given them permission on the folder, they can still access it because the link has granted them that access. Once they have access, they can use any valid path to reach the folder, including the generic document library link or the generic folder link. https://sharepointmaven.com/direct-access-vs-sharing-link-in-sharepoint-online/

Comment: But I can't replicate this same behaviour for a non AD user. For example if I share the folder with you then you won't be able to use the generic folder url. You must use that specific link. Is this expected?

Comment: Yes, this is expected. Users who are not part of your organization’s network, typically need the specific shared link to access the folder. These users don’t have the same level of access as internal or guest AD users. The user is authenticated through the link itself. This means they need the specific link to access the folder, and they can’t access the folder directly through a generic URL.

Comment: Ok I tried this. At the onset the user (link sharing) can't access the generic folder link. The user must use the specific link. However, once the user has accessed the folder via this specific link, then in future the user is able to use the generic links. Why is that.

Comment: This is because the user is authenticated through the link. Once the user has accessed the folder via the specific link, the system recognizes the user’s permissions to access that folder.

Comment: Another thing is that - if user opens a new browser session, then the generic folder urls stop working until the user uses the link shared url, and then the folder url start working again.